# Cannot get systemd StandardOutput=journal+console work in 15.04

Tags: systemd

I cannot to get ystemd StandardOutput=journal+console work in 15.04.
"StandardOutput=tty" works with fixed tty setting configuration or dynamic supply tty id with @.service.

Any reason why "journal+console" does not work?